# Using date filter with conditional

Tags: angularjs

I have the following date filter:

```
{{(selectedUser.created_at * 1000) | date:"d-MMM yyyy"}}
```

I don't show the date until I click on a user.

I'm having to multiply the `selectedUser.created_at` timestamp to convert to milliseconds but this then gives me an error: **NaN-undefined 0NaN** before I've even clicked on a user.

Without the multiplication i don't get the error but of course the date is wrong.

What's a good way around this?

Comment: How would we know, when a user is clicked??

Comment: Make your question clear. Add complete necessary code.

Comment: `selectedUser.created_at` will exist when user is selected - which is why the error happens in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
{{selectedUser.created_at ? ((selectedUser.created_at * 1000) | date:"d-MMM yyyy") : ''}}
```

Comment: I didn't realise you could do shorthand style conditionals. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can display it only when it's not `null`, like:

```
<span ng-show="selectedUser.created_at!=null">
    {{(selectedUser.created_at * 1000) | date:"d-MMM yyyy"}}
</span>
```